# Visual Studio 2008 Project vs. website debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

To create a website I chose 'create website' in VS2008.  I soon discovered that the compile options were not available (or at least I could not find the option) like creating serialization assemblies.  So I created a project and made the site into a 'project'.

As a web site I could have the page open in a browser, save a change to page in VS, and then just refresh the browser so see the changes.   As a project I now have to compile the entire site every time I make a change.  Note: When I deploy the site, I deploy it compiled only.

Is there any way to have a VS project mimic the debugging settings of a VS website?  Developing a website within a project is kind of a pain in comparison.  Conversely is there a way to compile and deploy a VS web site the same way I can with a VS project.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask a question. You're making a statement of well-known fact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Edit-And-Continue on the web tab of the properties of your web applicaton.

Comment: Thank you. I'm one step closer. I still have to manually break before I can change any class, then manually continue. With some changes I get a  "Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging" and I have to restart. Is there a way to avoid that?